# Class 'Memcached' not found error on silex, Symfony PHP

Tags: php, memcached

I have a silex, Symfony PHP project, it uses Memcached. It runs fine on Linux. I am having trouble getting this working on my Win7 64 bit machine. 
I get the following error

```
Class 'Memcached' not found
```

I have the memcached server up and running. If anybody could point out where I can download the memcached.dll, It will be great.

I can then load it as an extension in my php.ini file.

Thanks in advance.

PS: I already have the memcache.dll, I am looking for memcahced.sll

Comment: https://mnshankar.wordpress.com/2011/03/25/memcached-on-64-bit-windows/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here: http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/memcache/3.0.8/

And here: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php_memcache.dll

And may the google be with you.